# Can I set an automatic reply to a noreply@ address from SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm using Salesforce Marketing cloud to send emailings from several noreply@xxx.com address. These addresses exist but are not used.

If someone answers to an email regardless of the "noreply" address, I won't be aware of it.
Can I use Salesforce to send an automatic message replying to them that the emails adresses are not in use?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: There’s two ways of doing this. 1. You can add an automated response using the RMM or 2. you can created an email and set an auto reply using the sender profile.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by using the Reply Mail Management(RMM) feature. You can find it under Admin tab.For setting automatic replies you have 2 options available:
1.Default Response
2.Custom Response
Please see below screenshot of example set up.If you click the [view email] link next to default Response option, you can see the default text message associated with it. You can also define your custom replies by selecting the option "Create Custom Response" and you can specify custom message by going to [define email] option next to it.
You can find the detailed explanation here:
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/reply_mail_management/#replySubdomain

[image: Example of Reply Mail Management configuration]

Answer (score 0):

basically that noreply@XXX.com email address has been configured internally at your end, that has nothing to do with marketing cloud.

You can set up a mail internally(with your organization's IT team) to send a no response or delivery failure message to those who reply to no response.

https://richardkok.wordpress.com/2012/09/25/creating-a-no-reply-email-address-on-exchange-2010/